# Python Regex - Find numbers with comma in string

Tags: python, regex

I might have a string:

```
"Foo Bar, FooTown, $100,00"
```

Now I need to split that string by a comma, but that would split it wrongly, as the `$100,00` contains a comma too.

So I first want to look in the string, are there any numbers with a comma, and if so, replace the comma with a fullstop. so it looks like:

```
"Foo Bar, FooTown, $100.00"
```

#### EDIT:

It will always be small numbers, there won't be more than one `,` or `.`, but it might be $1 $10 $100 $1000

The string might or might not have spaces before the `,`

This is a SMS message.

Comment: What happens if the period is already being used as a thousands separator, such as 1.000.000,00 (as seen in European locales)?

Comment: Where do those strings come from?  I'd first try to fix *that*, before trying to parse strings in a broken format.

Comment: No that wont happen in my case. It will be small numbers like this

Comment: Are all commas not appearing in numbers followed by a space?  If so, you can splut at `", "`.

Comment: No there will not always be a space after is

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
>>> re.sub(r"(\d),(\d)", r"\1.\2", "Foo Bar, FooTown, $100,00")
'Foo Bar, FooTown, $100.00'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use negative lookaheads... those big forgottens in the super-powerful Python regular expression mechanisms...

You can make a regular expression to *split by commas who are not preceded by a digit or followed by a digit*.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import re
samples=[
    "Foo Bar, FooTown, $100,00",
    "$100,00, Foo Bar, FooTown",
    "Foo Bar, $100,00, FooTown",
    "$100,00, Foo Bar, FooTown,",
]

myRegex=re.compile(",(?!\d)|(?<!\d),")

for sample in samples:
    print "%s sample splitted: %s (%s items)" % (sample, myRegex.split(sample), len(myRegex.split(sample)))
```

Outputs:

```
Foo Bar, FooTown, $100,00 sample splitted: ['Foo Bar', ' FooTown', ' $100,00'] (3 items)
$100,00, Foo Bar, FooTown sample splitted: ['$100,00', ' Foo Bar', ' FooTown'] (3 items)
Foo Bar, $100,00, FooTown sample splitted: ['Foo Bar', ' $100,00', ' FooTown'] (3 items)
$100,00, Foo Bar, FooTown, sample splitted: ['$100,00', ' Foo Bar', ' FooTown', ''] (4 items)
```

I feel very sorry for the guys who developed the [re](http://docs.python.org/library/re#regular-expression-syntax) module in Python... I've seen these kind of lookaheads very scarcely used.

Answer (score 1):

A RegEx replace of the pattern `(\d),(\d)` with `\1.\2` will work. The `\d` matches any digit, and the parentheses around it means that the number will be remembered and `\1` will match the first one and `\2` will match the second one.

Comment: Wrong language :)  It's `\1` in Python, not `$1`, and you will have to use raw strings.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: Ah, yeah, I know RegEx, not Python (well, not particularly well). Fixing, though your answer's always gonna be better.

Comment: This answer explains what his happening, so the answers complement each other nicely. :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than fixing your data, why not fix your split?

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Foo Bar, FooTown, $100,00"
>>> re.split(r'(?<!\d),|,(?!\d)', s)
['Foo Bar', ' FooTown', ' $100,00']
```

This uses negative lookahead and lookbehind assertions to make sure that the comma is not surrounded by digits.

**edit:** Changed the regular expression from `r'(?<!\d),(?!\d)'` to `r'(?<!\d),|,(?!\d)'` to properly handle strings like "$100,00, Foo Bar, FooTown".  Thanks to BorrajaX for pointing out my error in the comments.

Comment: I also thought that, but I think that it won't split correctly strings like "$100,00, Foo Bar, FooTown", where the comma to split with is right after a digit, is that right?

Comment: @Borrajax:  Excellent point.  I changed the regular expression to deal with that.

Comment: Me too. I had a simmilar idea to yours **:-D** I like to see that someone is using the lookaheads feature... I haven't seen it used much... But people don't seem to like my anwer **:_(**