# mixed format CSV

Tags: python, regex, csv

I have the following (sample data)

```
name,phone,"addres 1, address 2",foo,bar
```

i have come across a kind of similar problem (with solution) here:
[Python Regex - Find numbers with comma in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870399/python-regex-find-numbers-with-comma-in-string)

what i want is to do a split and have the array look like

```
['name', 'phone', 'addres 1, address 2' ,'foo', 'bar']
```

im not brilliant with regex's so was hoping someone can help

Comment: Use the `csv` module, not regular expressions.

Comment: This is not a mixed format CSV. This is standard, valid CSV, that any library should support: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values#Basic_rules_and_examples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a regular-expression-shaped nail, so please put down that hammer. Python has a [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) for data like that instead.

```
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> data = StringIO('name,phone,"addres 1, address 2",foo,bar')
>>> for row in csv.reader(data):
...     print row
... 
['name', 'phone', 'addres 1, address 2', 'foo', 'bar']
```