# Python - recognize a number in a string

Tags: python, string, integer

I've followed the directions indicated on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265665/python-check-if-a-string-represents-an-int-without-using-try-except) using the method `.isdigit()` to check if a string is a number, and it fails for me.

I am simply trying:

```
print("final weight:", weight)
if weight.isdigit() == True:
    print("yes")
if weight.isdigit() == False:
    print("weight is not a digit")
```

It prints:

```
final weight:  1,873
weight is not a digit
```

I am very confused why this fails because `1,873` is in fact a number.

**UPDATE:**

Using RegEx worked. I simply do:

```
regnumber = re.compile(r"(\d),(\d) | (\d)")    #looks for numbers with commas and numbers without commas
if regnumber.search(weight):
    print("weight = an int")
```

Comment: you can use a regex for this (regular expression), see http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/8586346/python-regex-for-integer

Comment: @ralfhtp: I don't see this question handling the commas.

Comment: I took a couple of minutes to look through possible duplicates.  I can't find an existing question that deals with parsing a comma-enhanced input integer.  Is this *really* the first time someone has asked and let the question stand ???

Comment: http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-number-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a legal number in Python: it has a comma in the middle.  You and I recognize it, of course, but most computer languages don't allow commas in numbers like this.

If you need to recognize such a number, try searching on regular expressions for number recognition, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11870399/python-regex-find-numbers-with-comma-in-string#11870483) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917082/regular-expression-to-match-numbers-with-or-without-commas-and-decimals-in-text).

Second reference is from *ralf htp*'s comment on the main question.

---

STYLE UPDATE:

Checking a Boolean expression against a Boolean constant is redundant.  Just use the value in place:

```
if weight.isdigit():
    print("yes")
else:
    print("weight is not a digit")
```

Comment: Wow ok I feel dumb now. Sorry for muddying StackOverflow with such a novice question. Thanks a ton for responding though and directing me to a solution

Comment: Congratulations: you're human.  I expect that other people will have this problem ... and that I've probably missed this being a duplicate of an existing question.

Comment: So following that link you provided, is it as simple as `regnumber= re.compile(r"(\d),(\d)", r"\1.\2")     if regnumber.search(weight):    print("yes")`    ?

Comment: I *think* so.  I haven't used regular expressions in Python; I have local packages that do the conversions I need.  Try it and see?

Comment: Ok yeah so I just needed to read that link a closer. The guy who asked the question wanted to replace #'s with commas with #'s with periods; so I just took the regex that recognized #'s with commas and added a regex that recognizes plain numbers as well and it worked.. I'll update my question to provide an answer